# Combining sed with xargs to obtain a source and output file name

Tags: bash, sed, xargs

I have a situation where I have some input files like this:

```
M2U0001.MPG
M2U0180.MPG
```

And I want to run a command (in a Bash shell) on each similarly named file in the directory. I'd like the current file name to be given to this command as an input and a modified version of the filename to be given as an output file. Here's an example:

```
ffmpeg -i M2U0001.MPG M2U0001_fixed.MPG
```

I had the idea of using xargs and sed, but this is as far as I got:

```
ls -1 *.MPG | xargs -I{} ffmpeg -i {} `echo {} | sed -r 's/[0-9]{2,}/&_fixed/'`
```

But this results in the original filename being output in both positions.  Am I totally going about this the wrong way?

I found that if I echo the filename directly to the embedded chunk like this it works:

```
echo M2U0001.MPG | sed -r 's/[0-9]{2,}/&_fixed/'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or alternatively:

```
for i in *.MPG ; do ffmpeg -i $i `basename $i .MPG`_fixed.MPG ; done
```

*Thank [joshbaptiste](https://superuser.com/users/105549/joshbaptiste) for the [hint](https://superuser.com/a/357805/46005).*

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thanks for the demonstration of a for-loop in a one-liner.

Comment: be aware of the fact that this command will fail on filenames that contain spaces

Comment: True, I assumed file names are in that particular format, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Alex: a `for` loop will work perfectly well if you escape the *usage* of the variable. For example, `for i in *.MPG ; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "$(basename "$i" .MPG)_fixed.MPG" ; done`

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen yeah I know. basically a user needs to know about it.

Answer (score 3):

`for i in $(ls)` should not be used - the ls(1) output should not be used for parsing via scripts, etc. due to word splitting and is a common mistake I see in Bash scripts at my job.

In this case parameter expansion works fine and is not susceptible to word splitting errors.

```
for i in *.MPG; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%%.*}"_fixed.MPG ; done
```

Reference: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -iname "*.mpg" -exec sh -c "ffmpeg -i {} `echo {} | sed -e 's/\./_fixed\./'`" \;
```

Comment: This example does the same thing as my code.  The original filename is used as both the input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a specific variation:

```
ls -1 src/*.c | xargs -i sh -c "echo;gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E {} 2>&1 | grep -wi -e one -e two -e three -n | sed 's:^:{}\::'" | cat -s
```

A list of C source files,

```
ls -1 src/*.c
```

is piped to xargs, which executes the preprocessor in a child shell,

```
gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E {} 2>&1
```

which is subsequently piped into a desired grep command

```
grep -wi -e one -e two -e three -n
```

which is then piped into sed to prefix each line with the current file name:

```
sed 's:^:{}\::'
```

Finally, all the repeated blank lines are collapsed to single lines using cat:

```
cat -s
```

This works on a Red Hat Linux 6 system, but I assume it is general enough for other *nix systems.